# Why does my Google Maps API Request not work when I run it on a server

Tags: javascript, google-api, geolocation, geocoding

I am trying to find a way to calculate the traffic distance from one location to another. I found a script that works perfectly in my browser, but when I upload it to my web server and then open it.

It does not work.

I got a key from Google but can't figure out how to add it to the script.

*Here is the actual code*

```js
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

var request = {
  origin      : 'amsterdam',
  destination : 'rome',
  travelMode  : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if ( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ) {
    var output = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
    document.getElementById("dump").innerHTML = output;
    
  }
  else {

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<p id="dump"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `Google Maps API` key in the query string of the URL, in the `src` attribute of the `script` tag:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```